# What software should I get for web development and design?

Tags: 14.04, graphics, web-development, web-design

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my brand new PC. Beforehand, I was doing web development at work only for when we needed it (like HTML emails etc.) so I haven't a full understanding as to what I fully need.. I know I need an IDE (Think I'm going with Sublime Text) but what do I fully need to officially publish websites (I plan to freelance on the side of work), I can code HTML and CSS really well and PHP only adequatly but it's all just been given to me so I don't have a full understanding as to what I need.. could someone help list types of software - not necessarily name software just types so image manipulation, IDE etc. etc.

Thanks for any help given

-Trey

Comment: Hey guys, I've checked to see if there is an answer in those questions, but my question isn't IDE specific it's the whole of web development and design, not just the IDE :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't always need to use a IDE you can just develop using a simple ***text editor*** like (***"gedit"*** on ubuntu). But if you're looking specifically for an IDE there's the "**`Bluefish`**" editor that can help you in the development but there are many others also. Since you're gonna be developing PHP websites you'll need a server and probably a database software if you're gonna be making SQL based websites, you can use **`LAMP`** (`Linux Apache Mysql and PHP) server, it includes the server and the database, the webserver is the most important and required software for PHP development.

Note that the webserver installed on your personal machine is just for development purposes you should avoid using it for hosting your website online.

For image and graphics - You can use "Gimp"(for image editing) and inkscape(for vectors)

You'll probably need browser plugins like firebug(for firefox) to help you debug you html css and javascript code directly from the browser.

Color Pickers(if you're gonna be doing the design too) like colorzila.

You may also need other kind of tools as you develop different websites according to your need. But to start, this is probably enough.

Answer (score 4):

First I install apache2, php, MySQL and phpMyAdmin

```
apt-get install apache2
apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql
apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

and my work directory is /var/www/html

I use **Gimp** for image editing and **Inkscape** for vectors.
For FTP client I use **FoleZilla**.

My favorite code editor is **Sublime Text 3** with plugins:

Package Control,
All Autocomplete,
AutoFileName,
Bootstrap 3 Snippets,
BracketHighlighter,
Browser Refresh,
CSS Format,
Emmet,
Git,
GitGutter,
Goto-CSS-Declaration,
LoremIpsum,
SideBarEnhancements,
SublimeLinter-csslint,
TrailingSpaces,
W3CValidators,
WordCount,

For free IDE I recommend [Netbeans HTML5 & PHP](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html)

I use FireFox + Developer tools (press F12).

From Developer tools Settings > Available Toolbox Buttons
   check "Grab a color from the page" and "Take a fullpage screenshot".

My Firefox Add-ons: Measurelt and Web Developer

Answer (score 1):

IDE
Bluegriffon

Aptana Studio

image manipulation
Gimp (Ubuntu Software Center

Image creation
Inkscape (Ubuntu Software Center)

FTP
Filezilla (Ubuntu Software Center)